# Python 2d Array Input using Maps and Split

Tags: python-3.x

How to take input into python 2d array using map and split because in competitive coding competition the inputs are given with space?
Is it the correct way to use?

```
a = numpy.empty((N,M))
for i in range(N):
  b=list(map(int,input().split()))
  a.append(b)
  a.append('\n')
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do, alse please explain what doenst work with your ode.

Comment: Inputs are given like this 1 2 3 4 , 4 5 6 7, 8 9 0 1. Here comma i used instead of newline. I have to store this in 2d python lists. I used the above code but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The original question is a bit confused. If you want to store it in a numpy array, I'd be inclined to use `np.genfromtxt`:

```
import io
import numpy as np

input = b"""\
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(np.genfromtxt(io.BytesIO(input)))
```

If, on the other hand, you want to store it in a list of list (although I can't see why this is preferable to a numpy array), this sort of approach should work:

```
import io

input = b"""\
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_of_lists = [[int(elt) for elt in line.split()] for line in io.BytesIO(input)]
    print(list_of_lists)
```